# Finding the gradient of best fit line in python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

How do I calculate the gradient of a best fit line in python? I have 2 arrays x and y that I plotted, and then made a best fit line using polyfit (found an example online). I am now trying to find the gradient of my best fit line but I am unsure how. I have tried looking at similar questions on here but nothing I have tried so far has worked. Here is my code:

```
x = np.array(a)
y = np.array(b)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.plot(np.unique(x), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 1))(np.unique(x)), color = 'k')
plt.xlim((0,100))
plt.ylim((0,100))
plt.show()
```

I then tried to do it by this as I'd seen on a similar question:

```
m = ((np.mean(x) * np.mean(y)) − (np.mean(x * y))/((np.mean(x))**2 − np.mean(x**2))
print(m)
```

But I am just getting errors. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slope is already returned by the polyfit function. So:

```
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
#For a linear polynomial (so ,1), the formula for the line = slope*x+intercept (ax+b)
```

Applied to your case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Example data
x = [0,1,2,3,4]
y = [1,2,5,8,1]
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

#Fit line
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

#Plot
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y) 
plt.plot(np.unique(x), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 1))(np.unique(x)), color = 'k')
plt.show()

print(slope)
```

Please refer to https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html